# How to substitute values from array to values in list in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an array (of numpy.ndarray type) like

```
arr=array([[1, 5, 1],
          [4, 2, 0]])
```

and a list of values:

```
values=['father','mother','sister','brother','aunt','uncle']
```

And I'd like to substitute numbers in array **arr** with items from list **values** using array's items as indices of list values:`arr[0,0]=values[arr[0,0]]`

Here an example of what I'd like to have

```
arr=array([['mother', 'uncle', 'mother'],
           ['aunt', 'sister', 'father']])
```

Is there any elegant pythonic way to do this?

Thanks for helping in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the numpy [take](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) function :

```
In [64]: np.take(values,arr)
Out[64]: 
array([['mother', 'uncle', 'mother'],
       ['aunt', 'sister', 'father']], 
      dtype='<U7')
```

The conversion is then automatic.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the `values` to a numpy array then use a simple indexing:

```
>>> values = np.array(values)
>>> 
>>> values[arr]
array([['mother', 'uncle', 'mother'],
       ['aunt', 'sister', 'father']], 
      dtype='|S7')
```

Read more about *indexing*: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html